# How to do a deepequals on a object in python

Tags: python, object, deepequals

Is there a function so that I can do

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value_1 = 42

x = Test()
y = Test()
deepequals(x, y) == True
x.value = 7
deepequals(x, y) == False
y.value = 7
deepequals(x, y) == True
```

However, by default, it would always be false because x and y are different instances of Test

Comment: Define `__eq__` of your class `Test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `__eq__` (equals) "magic method":

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value_1 = 42
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

where `__dict__` holds all of the instance attributes. This will return `True` when two objects have all the same values for all the same attributes. This gives the result you want:

```
>>> x = Test()
>>> y = Test()
>>> x == y
True
>>> x.value = 7
>>> x == y
False
>>> y.value = 7
>>> x == y
True
```

To support comparisons with objects that do not have a `__dict__` attribute (like those defined in C or using `__slots__` instead) you can either check for that attribute first using `hasattr`:

```
return hasattr(other, '__dict__') and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

or access it safely using `getattr` with a default:

```
return self.__dict__ == getattr(other, '__dict__', None)
```

Comment: `return hasattr(other, '__dict__') and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__`

Comment: @v_b yes, that would be safer in cases where you're dealing with objects that may not have a `__dict__`, like those using `__slots__` instead.

Comment: What I mean is, `x == None`, `x == 1`, or `x == {}` would fail for `x = Test()`.

Comment: @v_b we're agreeing, those are other examples of objects that don't have a `__dict__`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value_1 = 42
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
             self.__class__ == other.__class__ and
             self.value_1 == other.value_1)

t1 = Test()
t2 = Test()
print(t1 == t2)
```

output

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement `__eq__` of your class. Then you can use the standard comparison operator:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 42

    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return self.value == other.value

x = Test()
y = Test()
print (x == y)
x.value = 7
print (x == y)
y.value = 7
print (x == y)
```